# vba creating serial number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to write a vba code/formula that will create serial numbers starting from a specific number and this serial number should be created based on a value of another cell. Example below:

if cells in column G="Y", then Nothing, else if cells in column A are equal moving down, then serial number should start from H1+1 i.e 1178 and this serial number should remain 1178 as long as the cells in column A are equal. Once they change to a different name and G column is "N", then the serial number should change to the next number i.e 1179

Looping until the end.

[image]

tried different formulas but did not work properly

Comment: `=IF(A2<>A1,H1+1,H1)`?. What should the serial number in cells `H3` and `H7` be? In other words, what if column G is `N`? The specific expected output might be helpful.

Comment: serial number in H3 should read as 1178 and H4 as well, since A2 and A3 have the same value. Serial number for H7, H8 and H9 should be 1179 since A7, A,8 and A9 have the same value, and so on. If any cell in column G have the value "Y" then serial number should be blank ""

Comment: Then include an if() that tests for "Y" ie if(G1="Y",do_this,do_that). something like if(G1="Y","",IF(A2<>A1,H1+1,H1))

Comment: Can a value of column A repeat itself further on, let say first we have `A`, then `B` then `A` again. How to count that? Have you considered using (X)MATCH?

Comment: @P.b I have used a match() with an "extending range" as it drags down like A$2:A2.

Comment: I was just suggesting that 

Comment: It is not gonna work that way, this is just an example of 9 rows, the file i have is 1000+ rows and the serial numbers should depend on the cell H1. when i change the number in cell H1, all lines should change according to that.

Comment: I used MATCH but it is working only with the first set of serial numbers (i.e A3 to A4), but in the next set of serial numbers (i.e A7 to A9) it is still giving me the same serial number, it doesnt recognize that it has to read the last number and then add 1 to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest way but should work:

[image]

```
=IF(G2="Y";"";IF(A2=A1;MAX($H$1:H1);MAX($H$1:H1)+1))
```

Notice this formula will work as long as values in column A are sorted as your example, so same values will be adjacent.